# transition laterally to anchor inside page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not an web developer, but normally I can figure out how stuff works on a website. Today I was browsing http://www.massivehealth.com/ and I lost a good couple of minutes to try to understand how they do the transitions inside the page. Can anyone explain to me? is it something native from jquery? or some fancy java script?

If it is some sort of jave script how does it work? The feeling is that it limits my "field of view" on the page and not that it renders another page. Is that correct? If so how does it do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can break the website in parts, it is pretty clear to understand how it is structured.

1. A Big Division (`DIV`) or planned sequence of multiple `DIV's` consisting of the whole `HTML` and `CSS` Design structure and attributes respectively.
2. An effective use of JavaScript Frameworks like `Jquery` or `Mootools` and their `modals` to slide it down to a particular portion of the Div with a transition or other different effets with the respective content that corresponds to that link. Thats it.

From the Demo link that you have provided, I have found out a link to [the Tutorials for creating Horizontal, vertical and diagonal Scroll](http://www.queness.com/post/356/create-a-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-sliding-content-website-with-jquery) that is very much an introduction to the link that you have mentioned.

Hope this Helps.